# Averaging floating value in assembly

Tags: assembly

I have to get average. In C++ since I don't pass it the length of the array 
I don't   know how to divide it by that.

Here's how I'm passing my values in C++

```
extern "C" double Average (long [6]); 

        _Average proc


        finit
        mov  ecx, 6  ; number of elements
        mov  ebx, [esp + 4] ; address of the array
        fldz

   L1: 
        fld REAL4 PTR [ebx]  ; get elements of array
        fadd
        add ebx, 4

        loop L1
        fdiv DWORD PTR [esp + 4]

        fwait 

        ret   

       _Average endp
```

Answer (score 1):

Then pass the length. Or, since it's a fixed-sized array of length 6, just assume it's 6.

Comment: Other than a declaration, there's no C++ code anywhere. What do you mean, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You already know that it's six elements long, since you're using that as your loop count (in `ecx`) and it is specified in the prototype. The only alternative is to pass another parameter with the length (as you would have to do in pure C++ anyway).

You also need to use `fild` instead of `fld` to load a `long`, since it is not a floating point variable, as well as changing `REAL4 PTR` to `DWORD PTR`. Alternatively, change `long` to `float`. (Another alternative is changing `long` to `double`, though this changes the size of the data type which will require more modifications.)

Comment: since it is a homework question I am not supposed to make any changes in C++

Comment: Zooba I made the changes that you recommend, but I'm still not getting the right average. I changed fld to fild, changed REAL4 to DWORD. can you show me how should my fdiv look like. I have another question, should fldz still be used if I am using fdiv instead of fidiv.